# Coinbase Wallet extension does not return pending transaction from eth_getTransactionByHash

Tags: web3-providers, coinbase

I encountered a problem while integrating CoinBase wallet into a DApp.

Previously, only MetaMask was supported. With MetaMask, I was able to send a TX hash of a pending transaction to `eth_getTransactionByHash` (for example, the hash of a TX I just sent) and get a result. (Of course, `eth_getTransactionReceipt` would not give me anything.)

With the CoinBase wallet Chrome extension however, `eth_getTransactionByHash` doesn't give me any result for a pending transaction. Only once the transaction is confirmed, I get it returned.

Is there some way to get the pending transaction data with the CoinBase wallet as Web3 provider too?